# Tail bounds for sub-Gaussian and sub-exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems, concentration-of-measure

Massart and Laurent (see [[1](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Faos%2F1015957395)], Lemma 1 on page 1325] give tail bounds for $\chi^2$ random variables.

A corollary of their bound is the following:

$$P\left[\frac{1}{k} X \leq 1- 2\sqrt{\frac{x}{k}} \right]\leq \exp (-x) $$
$$P\left[\frac{1}{k} X \geq 1+2\sqrt{\frac{x}{k}}+2 \frac{x}{k} \right]\leq \exp (-x) $$

I am looking for similar statements for sub-Gaussian and sub-exponential random variables, but could only find the following statement for independent $\sigma^2$-sub-Gaussian RV:

$$P\left[ \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \geq t \right]\leq \exp \left(-\frac{n t^2}{\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i^2}\right) $$

which is similar to the second concentration inequality ("upper tail") by Massart and Laurent. I couldn't find any equivalent for the first one ("lower tail").

Furthermore, I couldn't find any inequalities for sub-exponential RV without any additional prerequisites (e.g., maximum known).

Is there any similar statements to the first ("upper") bound by Massart and Laurent for sub-Gaussian distributions and similar statements for both bounds for sub-exponential distributions?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where are you looking? Chapter 2 of [Vershynin's High Dimension Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) has two-sided tail bounds for both sub-gaussian and sub-exponential RVs.